Why does the Gaza Strip use Israeli currency?
Why does the Gaza Strip, along with the West Bank, use Israeli currency?
The Wikipedia article Protocol on Economic Relations says that Palestinian territories have to accept that currency and can't create their own currency, but I don't know why Israel wanted this, or why the Palestinians agreed to it, or why not only the West Bank but even the Gaza Strip continued to honour such an agreement.


I don't know why Israel wanted this

Controlling someone else's currency comes with plenty of advantages. See e.g. the advantages that the US derives when it e.g. want to sanction transactions in dollars by Iran or whomever else.
Reportedly Hamas kept many of their financial assets in Turkey, Algeria, Sudan, UAE etc. for this (and similar) reasons, although IIRC many of those countries would deny this was the case.


why the Palestinians agreed to it

What choice do they have? It's called occupied territories for a reason. Even in Gaza, which was arguably less occupied until last year, they were pretty dependant on workers going to Israel (about a quarter of them; in the West Bank it was even higher, around 1/3) etc.

Given the high degree of economic inequality between Israel and the OPT (in terms of income per capita etc.) and the lack (AFAIK) of a risk sharing mechanism, monetary union theory probably says that they shouldn't really have the same currency, as those are among the criteria, IIRC. OTOH some of other criteria like labor mobility across the region (at least when there's not a war) argue for it.
But the currencies of failed states tend not to have much appeal, even to their own population. And Palestine is arguably in that category (and Gaza right now even more so). Even if they had a currency of their own, they'd probably have to peg it (e.g. via a currency board) to some "strong" currency like the dollar or euro etc. Which is pretty much using a foreign currency in all but name.

As much as any of the practical reasons, a currency is a symbolic badge of sovereignty.

@ohwilleke: perhaps that comment is better fitting under Ian Ringrose's answer?

That answer didn't exist when I made the comment.

When Israel first fully removed all Israeli military and settlements from the Gaza Strip there was practically no restriction on movement of the Gaza population into Israel for work/trade for a few years.  There was little direct trade with other countries.
So it was natural for Gaza to use the currency that most trade was done in and most wages of the people who crossed into Israel daily to work where paid in.
Without stable government/politics it is unlikey anyone would have wished to keep money in a Gaza currency or anyone outside of Gaza would have agreed to trade in it, so little point to Hamas creating their own currency.

Currency management is complicated. Currency management for poor countries in distress is even harder. Countries like Venezuela and Zimbabwe show how hard it is to keep stable prices when the authorities can resort to printing currency to finance current spending.
Using the Israeli currency solves a complicated problem for Palestinian authorities.
If Hamas, or some other Palestinian authority, were to issue their own currency, it's a safe bet that hyperinflation would occur within a few months.
The famous German hyperinflation of 1923 is a relevant example: Germany eventually solved their currency management problems by handing over the money-printing powers to a bureaucratic agency protected from short-term political influence. Fast-forward to 2000: The Eurozone countries did much the same thing by creating the ECB (European Central Bank).
Given the level of economic integration between Palestinian territories, occupied or not, and Israel, standard "Optimal Currency Area" arguments suggest that using the Israeli currency is the best of all the available options. The deal breaker here is the large number of Palestinians who work in Israel and are paid in the Israeli currency. From that perspective, it is better than using the more stable U.S. dollar or Euro.
Now how Palestinian authorities managed to reach an optimal decision in the context they are operating in is itself an interesting, but separate question.
[Note that I am no expert on Palestinian or Israeli economic matters]
